# Call class function with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to access the `doSomething` function when the button that the render function creates is clicked? I get the following error instead.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getMethod is not defined

main.js

```
    class Div {
    constructor(div){
        this.div = div;
    }

    init(){
        this.getMethod();
    }

    getMethod(){

        var div = this.div;
        var createButton = {
            render: function(){

                let button = `
                    <button
                    onclick="getMethod.doSomething(this)"
                    type="button">
                    Click Me!
                    </button>
                `;

                div.innerHTML = button;
            },

            doSomething: function(){
                // do something
            }

        }

        createButton.render();
    }
}


const div = new Div(document.querySelector('div'));
div.init();
```

Comment: Where's the `addEventListener` which is mentioned in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

- Event handlers in html attributes (e.g.`onclick`) get run in global scope, yet `getMethod` is defined in a local scope, the scope of your class.
- `getMethod` does not have a property `doSomething`, I think you meant to write `createButton.doSomething`

To fix the first issue you have to define your button as an object, not just as text. Since text doesn't know anything about scope. Then you can [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a handler for the `click` event. In the handler callback function's you will have access to all variables in your local scope (the scope of the `getMethod` function)

```js
class Div {
  constructor(div){
    this.div = div;
  }

  init(){
    this.getMethod();
  }

  getMethod(){

    var div = this.div;
    var createButton = {
      render: function(){
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.type = "button";
        button.textContent = "Click Me!";
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          createButton.doSomething(this)
        })
        //clear inner html / delete all children
        div.innerHTML = '';
        div.appendChild(button);
      },

      doSomething: function(){
        console.log("do something");
      }

    }

    createButton.render();
  }
}

const divElem = document.getElementById("mydiv");
const div = new Div(divElem);
div.init();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```